# Criar um algoritmo, em JS, para listar todos os números primos menores ou igual a N

Tags: javascript, algoritmo

Preciso criar um algoritmo em `Javascript`, para listar todos os números primos menores ou igual a um determinado número.

```
function primeNumber (num){
    var num = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= num; i++){
        if ((num % 1 === 0) && (num % num === 0)){
            return (primeNumber(i));
        }
    }
}
console.log(primeNumber(num));
```

Onde estou errando?

Comment: O resto da divisão de um número por 1, ou o resto dadivisão por ele mesmo, sempre será zero. Reveja a definição de número primo e seu algoritmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceito:

[Para identificar um número primo devemos dividi-lo sucessivamente por números primos como: 2, 3, 5. . . e verificar se a divisão é exata (em que o resto é zero) ou não exata (onde o resto é diferente de zero).](https://brasilescola.uol.com.br/matematica/como-reconhecer-os-numeros-primos.htm)

- [Se o resto da divisão for zero o número não é primo.](https://brasilescola.uol.com.br/matematica/como-reconhecer-os-numeros-primos.htm)
- [Se nenhum resto for zero, o número é primo.](https://brasilescola.uol.com.br/matematica/como-reconhecer-os-numeros-primos.htm)

Exemplo simples em código onde a função `primeNumbers` vai interar de 0 até a quantidade de números e os `isPrime` vai verificar se o mesmo realmente é número primo:

```js
function primeNumbers(num) {
  let numbers = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
    if (isPrime(i)){
      numbers.push(i);
    }
  }
  return numbers;
}
function isPrime(num) {
  for(let i = 2; i <num; i++)
    if(num % i === 0) {
        return false
    };
  return num > 1;
}
console.log(primeNumbers(13));
```

onde a operação trará todos os números entre o número informado.

Comment: Este seu programa lista os número ímpares e não primos.

Comment: realmente eu vou arrumar @anonimo

Comment: @anonimo obrigado foi arrumado agora!

Answer (score 3):

A definição mais comum é que "um número é primo se for divisível por 1 e por ele mesmo" ou então "é todo o número com dois e somente dois divisores, ele próprio e a unidade". Sendo assim, por exemplo, o número 7 é primo por ser divisível apenas por 1 e por 7.

1. Por definição o número 2 é um número primo portanto devemos testar a partir do divisor `2`.
2. Se na função `primeNumber` houver algum divisor que o resto da divisão seja igual a `0` ele não é primo e podemos parar com a verificação.

```js
function primeNumber(num) {
    for (var divisor = 2; divisor < num; divisor++) 
    if (num % divisor == 0) return false;
    return true;
}

var determinadoNumero = 50;

for (var i = 2; i < determinadoNumero; i++) if (primeNumber(i)) console.log(i);
```

> o número `2` é o único número primo que é par.

Answer (score -3):

```
Criar função para mostrar numeros primos


exibirNumerosPrimos(25);

function exibirNumerosPrimos(limite){
    for(let numero = 2; numero <= limite; numero++){
        if(NumerosPrimo(numero)) console.log(numero);
    }
}


function NumerosPrimo(numero){
    for(let divisor =2; divisor < numero; divisor++){
        if(numero % divisor === 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```